# How to install and use semantic-ui-react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, semantic-ui

I want to build a web client using react.js and semantic ui. There is a node package to use semantic-ui with react.js; [semantic ui react](http://react.semantic-ui.com/usage). I have already installed this package on my computer following the instructions on [react.semantic-ui.com/usage](http://react.semantic-ui.com/usage), but upon testing the with a simple webpage.

I think I have this issue because I failed to use this last instruction:
`import '.../semantic/dist/semantic.min.css';`. The `semantic` folder has been generated in my project main folder, but the `dist` folder and the `semantic.min.css` have not been generated yet. Where and how should I use this?

**NB:** I also tried adding this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css"></link>` to my `index.html` page and the page was style as expected. I don't want to use this option as I cannot change the them with it.

Comment: I have succeeded to generate the `semantic/dist/*` files. I don't know yet how to `import '.../semantic/dist/semantic.min.css'` and where to import it.

Comment: `semantic-ui-css` is a package dependency of SUIR

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First - install css `npm install semantic-ui-css --save`
Then - import in at the index.js page (the very top level)
 `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';`

Comment: Though if you want a custom build (say a theme), you'd need to `npm install semantic-ui` and run the gulp build task (or add it to the CI) : https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/build-tools.html

Comment: thanks. why does it have to import in the index.js page?

Comment: just to be included in the final bundle, and be available everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

First, use one of below package managers to install semantic UI react package.

**For npm users:**

```
npm install semantic-ui-react
```

**For yarn users:**

```
yarn add semantic-ui-react
```

Then add this import line to your `index.js`

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
```

That's all.

Comment: From where does come "semantic-ui-css" ? There might be missing a `npm install semantic-ui-css`

Comment: @challet from the dependency of SUIR. No need to install it twice.

Answer (score 2):

For npm user:

```
npm i semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css
```

Answer (score 0):

[semantic-ui-css](https://github.com/semantic-org/semantic-ui) is a package dependency of [Semantic-ui-react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) (*SUIR*) and is the **css only** distribution with a unique theme. [Semantic-ui](https://github.com/semantic-org/semantic-ui-css) is written in `Less` and provides a larger and finer control (*per component*) over the production of the final stylesheet (`dist/semantic.min.css`). 
It delivers several themes easy to derive to create your own, and a proper picture about how to keep a big and complex css well organized and not invasive with *less*.

in node v12, the installation of sui-css may fail,
complaining that `ReferenceError: primordials is not defined`. See 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58394828/1874016.

You can also
`git clone https://github.com/semantic-org/semantic-ui`
apply the patch above in here.
and `yarn install`

Note the default `semantic.min.css` size is **628Kb** and you probably don't need the styling for *all* the components it has.

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install sematic-ui-react sematic-ui-css --save
```

- In your root file probably src/index.js add

  import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
- Some common layouts can be found [here ]:(https://semantic-ui.com/usage/layout.html)

Comment: How is your answer any way different from @DonskikhAndrei's?

Comment: Same as [Donskikh Andrej's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46788570/2289835)