# How to fix "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have installed Node.js modules by 'npm install', and then I tried to do `gulp sass-watch` in a command prompt. After that, I got the below response.

```
[18:18:32] Requiring external module babel-register
fs.js:27
const { Math, Object, Reflect } = primordials;
                                  ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
```

I have tried this before `gulp sass-watch`:

```
npm -g install gulp-cli
```

Comment: If anyone is getting this issue during automated execution of gulp tasks via the Visual Studio Task Runner (particular after updating VS), see here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72709758/1549918

Answer (score 914, accepted):

I hit the same error. I suspect you're using Node.js 12 and Gulp.js 3. That combination does not work: *[Gulp.js 3 is broken on Node.js 12 #2324](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2324)*

A previous workaround from Jan. does not work either: *[After update to Node.js 11.0.0 running Gulp.js exits with 'ReferenceError: internalBinding is not defined' #2246](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2246)*

Solution: Either upgrade to Gulp.js 4 or downgrade to an earlier version of Node.js.

Comment: I'm using node `v12.1.0` and gulp `gulp@4.0.2` but it doesn't work

Comment: I'd recommend using npm-shrinkwrap.json solution posted by Valentin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58394828/2726785, even though this is the accepted solution.

Comment: I use node `v14` and gulp `v4`. And I still get the issue :(

Comment: Upgraded Gulp to 4 and had to fix a couple Task issues in my gulpfile.js but that did the trick.

Comment: You can also use nvm to use several node versions

Comment: use node package manager https://www.npmjs.com/package/n, which can be used switch between the whatever the node version you want.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I'm using node `v16.17.1` and gulp `4.0.2`  Though in my case I had to upgrade gulp both globally and in the dev dependency. Essentially running `npm install --global gulp-cli` and then `npm install --save-dev gulp`

Comment: This solution is right but it also can be happened becouse of version of npm, for me downgrade from npm 9.3.1 to 6.14.4 helped

Comment: Upgraded to the latest gulp version to remove the error (using node 18.17.x) but now getting the error `Task function must be specified`

Answer (score 947):

We encountered the same issue when updating a legacy project depending on `gulp@3.9.1` to Node.js 12+.

These fixes enable you to use Node.js 12+ with `gulp@3.9.1` by overriding `graceful-fs` to version `^4.2.11`.

### If you are using pnpm

`pnpm` supports [overriding some dependencies versions](https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmoverrides). To do it, you should add a `pnpm` section in your package.json file:

```json
{
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11"
    }
  }
}
```

### If you are using yarn v1

Yarn v1 [supports resolving a package to a defined version](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/).
You need to add a `resolutions` section to your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "resolutions": {
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11"
  }
}
```

Thanks [@jazd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1650473/jazd) for this way to solve the issue.

### If you are using npm

Run this command to know which version of npm you are using:

```bash
npm -v
```

It will return a version number `<major>.<minor>.<patch>` such as `8.4.0`.

If your version is v8.3.0 or above, then you can override the version of `graceful-fs` by adding [an `overrides` section](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) in your package.json file:

```json
{
  "overrides": {
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11"
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you need to use [`npm-force-resolutions`](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions) as a preinstall script to be able to override the version of `graceful-fs` by changing your package.json file like this:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11"
  }
}
```

`npm-force-resolutions` will alter the `package-lock.json` file to set `graceful-fs`to the wanted version before the `install` is done.

If you are using a custom `.npmrc` file in your project and it contains either a proxy or custom registry, you might need to change `npx npm-force-resolutions` to `npx --userconfig .npmrc npm-force-resolutions` because some versions of `npx` don't use the current folder `.npmrc` file by default.

### Origin of the problem

This issue stems from the fact that `gulp@3.9.1` [depends](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/package.json#L47) on `graceful-fs@^3.0.0` which monkeypatches Node.js `fs` module.

This used to work with Node.js until version 11.15 (which is a [version](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) from a development branch and shouldn't be used in production).

[`graceful-fs@^4.0.0`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs#v4) does not monkeypatch Node.js `fs` module anymore, which makes it compatible with Node.js > 11.15 (tested and working with versions 12, 14, 16, 18 and 20).

Note that this is not a perennial solution but it helps when you don't have the time to update to `gulp@^4.0.0`.

Comment: @Valentin this worked for me, but how did it work? From what I've read, besides being publishable, npm-shrinkwrap.json should behave the same as package-lock.json. Why don't they behave the same here? Why is npm-shrinkwrap.json needed to fix this?

Comment: What it does is that it overrides graceful-fs version to a newer version (v4+) which does not monkey patch nodejs fs module anymore (see graceful-fs README). Thankfully this is enough to get everything working.

Comment: `npx npm-force-resolutions` doesn't work anymore without a valid `package-lock.json`. To work around that, use `"preinstall": "npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts && npx npm-force-resolutions"` ([source](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions/issues/10#issuecomment-676804889)).

Comment: @rustyx I haven't had this issue since the package-lock.json was committed in source control long before the preinstall script was added. As of today, I would recommend using Node.js 16.14.0 and up which comes with npm 8.3.0+ to use be able to use the overrides solution.

Comment: I can´t thank you enough! Works perfectly, adding the "overrides" key to package.json using npm > 8.3.0!

Comment: Note: If you try this but it's not working, try deleting `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and then running `npm install` again (after deleting `node_modules`, of course)

Comment: You need to figure out which package is using the `old graceful-fs`.
For example, you have an `some` package that has the `old graceful-fs`. you will still get the error even if you have overridden `graceful-fs`. so you have to override `some` too.

`
"overrides": {
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11",
    "some": "^9.3.1"
  }
`

Answer (score 509):

## Fix it in one minute:

Just follow [these steps](https://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-error/). I'm on Windows 10 and it worked perfectly for me!

1. In the same directory where you have `package.json` create a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file with the following contents:

   ```
       {
         "dependencies": {
           "graceful-fs": {
               "version": "4.2.2"
            }
         }
       }
   ```
2. Run `npm install`, and don't worry, it will update `npm-shrinkwrap.json` with a bunch of content.
3. Run `gulp` to start the project.

Comment: *Be Warned* This is just a temporary solution, if you run `npm i` once again, it's broken again.

Comment: Because `shrinkwrap.json` file is modified after `npm install`, you need to delete it if you want to run it again.
The solution is to add a line in your `package.json` `scripts` node: `"preinstall": "cp npm-shrinkwrap.gulp.json npm-shrinkwrap.json"`, where `npm-shrinkwrap.gulp.json`  is the needed one, which will be copied into  `npm-shrinkwrap.json` before npm install. (Change `cp` to `copy` on Windows)

Comment: I have worked it, I had npm@14 version

Answer (score 147):

Use the following commands and install **Node.js v11.15.0**:

```bash
npm install -g n

sudo n 11.15.0
```

will solve

> ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node

Referred from @Terje Norderhaug @Tom Corelis answers.

Comment: If it still doesn't work try this (after the above commands): npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: npm install -g n on my (windows 64) machine produces an error:
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@6.1.3: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: I had node 12 previously, downgrading helped me.

Answer (score 55):

Use the following commands to install Node.js v11.15.0 and Gulp.js v3.9.1:

```bash
npm install -g n

sudo n 11.15.0

npm install gulp@^3.9.1
npm install
npm rebuild node-sass
```

It will solve this issue:

> ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node

Comment: Please do not use a shortliving NodeJS branch (all odd version numbers like 9 and 11), use NodeJS 10.

Comment: `n` in `sudo n 11.15.0` is supposedly installed in the first step, `npm install -g n`. What is that? Does it still work?

Comment: In case you face permissions issues running `npm install gulp@^3.9.1` follow the steps from this guide https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 49):

For me, [Diego Fortes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node-js/60921145#60921145) works with one small change.

Here is my workflow if this error appears:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm install gulp`
3. create file *npm-shrinkwrap.json* with

   ```
   {
     "dependencies": {
       "graceful-fs": {
           "version": "4.2.2"
        }
     }
   }
   ```
4. `npm install` (again) (Not `npm install gulp` again! Very important - otherwise the error will be come back)
5. gulp (now working)

Comment: This is just a temporary solution, if you run `npm i` once again, it's broken again.

Answer (score 32):

Using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage what Node.js version you're using, running the following commands worked for me:

```sh
cd /to/your/project/
nvm install lts/dubnium
nvm use lts/dubnium
yarn upgrade # or `npm install`
```

Comment: Please do not use a shortliving NodeJS branch (all odd version numbers like 9 and 11), use NodeJS 10. Also use `10` instead of the code name.

Comment: For Windows use [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

Comment: Dubnium = Node.js 10.24.1

Answer (score 28):

Gulp 3.9.1 doesn't work with Node v12.x.x, and if you upgrade to Gulp 4.0.2, you have to completely change gulpfile.js with the new syntax (series & parallels). So your best bet is to downgrade to Node.js v 11.x.x (the 11.15.0 version worked fine for me) by simply using the following code in a terminal:

```
nvm install 11.15.0
nvm use 11.15.0 # Just in case it didn't automatically select the 11.15.0 as the main node.
nvm uninstall 13.1.0
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Answer (score 28):

## TL:DR

Gulp `3.*` doesn't work on Node.js `12.*` or above. You have to downgrade Node.js, or upgrade Gulp.

> If you are short on time, downgrade Node.js to v11.* or below; if you need newer features, and have time to possibly fix a load of broken dependencies, upgrade Gulp to 4.* or above!

As others have already mentioned, Gulp 3.* is not supported on Node.js 12 or above, so you will have to downgrade your Node version to 11.* or below, OR upgrade your Gulp to 4.0.

The best option depends ultimately on how much time you have, as upgrading Gulp brings benefits of cleaner gulpfiles and in-built control over having tasks run in [series or parallel](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks), but also relies on you rewriting your gulpfile to a new syntax, and *might* (read: probably will - see end of this comment) cause conflicts with some dependencies.

---

### Downgrading Node.js

This is the easiest and quickest option. Especially if you use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) or [nvm](https://nvm.sh), as these allow you to very quick install and switch between Node.js versions.

#### Installing Node.js version on N

```sh
n 10.16.0
```

#### Installing a Node.js version on NVM

```sh
nvm install 10.16.0
```

Once you have done this, you *may* need to rebuild your [npm dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rebuild) or alternatively remove both your `node_modules` folder *and* your `package-lock.json` file and reinstalling your dependencies. Though if you are merely reverting to a preexisting Node.js version, you should probably be fine.

---

## Upgrading Gulp

As mentioned above, this is a more time-intensive task, but it might bring benefits in the long run. For example, Node.js 12 has now introduced native support for ES Modules (behind an experimental flag) and full support in Node.js 13.

You may need to upgrade Node.js to use that, forcing you to upgrade Gulp. Or you may simply want the benefits of using Gulp 4, as it offers better and more efficient control over writing tasks.

There are a number of articles on this already, so I won't elaborate any further on the specifics, but to reiterate - **this is not a quick job**. Depending on the size of your project, there may be some notable rewriting required, and you may have dependencies that break. If you are in short supply of time, you should opt for simply downgrading Node.js, at least temporarily.

---

### But I already have Gulp 4, and it still doesn't work!

If, like me, you are already using Gulp 4+ (I was using Gulp `4.0.2`, originally on Node.js 10) and have recently upgraded (I upgraded to Node.js 13.8.0) are you are still getting the issue, it may be because a dependency is relying on an older version of Gulp, and that is getting caught in the pipeline.

In my case, `gulp-combine-mq` was a dependency using Gulp 3.9.*. Disabling this task in my gulpfile allowed Gulp to run again.

If this happens, you have a few options. You can,

1. Go without the plugin if it's not absolutely necessary
2. Find an alternative,
3. Fix the plugin

Needless to say, if you have several plugins that rely on an older version of Gulp - especially if these plugins are vital for your application - this is where there can be a huge additional chunk of time spent in upgrading Gulp (hence the warnings above).

If this happens, it is best to just downgrade Node.js, at least until patches can be issued.

Comment: To me, this is also my case. I was using Gulp 4, but a old gulp plugin was internally depending on old graceful-fs version. Culprit can be found using `npm ls graceful-fs` - a package using graceful-fs with version below 4 will be causing this issue. Remove it from gulpfile, use an alternative or upgrade it to fix the issue.

Answer (score 28):

> **Simple and elegant solution**

Just follow these steps. It worked perfectly with npm install running multiple times or installing any other modules or even publishing project to artifactory.

In the same directory where you have package.json create a **npm-shrinkwrap.json** file with the following contents:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "graceful-fs": {
        "version": "4.2.2"
     }
  }
}
```

Run npm install, and don't worry, it'll update npm-shrinkwrap.json with a bunch of content. Let's get rid of this updates by updating **package.json** scripts options.

```
"scripts": {
    "preshrinkwrap": "git checkout -- npm-shrinkwrap.json",
    "postshrinkwrap": "git checkout -- npm-shrinkwrap.json"
}
```

Now you can run npm install and your npm-shrinkwrap.json will be intact and will work forever.

Comment: Saved me from preserving npm-shrinkwrap.json manually, thanks!

Comment: Great to see my first post on stack overflow helped being you as the first person @dblazeski :)

Comment: @saumilsdk when I install another module afterwards, e.g. `npm i bla`, it only installs the graceful-fs + the new one but all other modules are missing then, is it the same for you?

Comment: @NthDegree no i didn't see that happening. You should be seeing some changes in your package.config file.

Comment: Nice, but with npm v7 those directives went away. They are never executed; as per https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2520

Answer (score 16):

I had the same error. I finally fixed that when I updated all packages and then mentioned the **same Node.js engine version and npm version** in `package.json` as it is in my local working system.

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
 }
```

I was getting this error when deploying on [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku).

For more, check out [Heroku support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version).

Comment: This is workaround and not a fix. Sometimes we cannot downgrade node version from 12 to 10.

Comment: Hey, you just need to be sure about the node engine version are the same on Heroku and on the local machine. :)

Answer (score 10):

Check Node.js version:

```
 node --version
```

Check gulp version:

```
gulp -v
```

If Node.js >=12 and gulp <= 3, do one of the following:

1. Upgrade gulp

```
sudo npm install -g gulp
```

2. Downgrade node

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 11.15.0
```

*[How to Upgrade (or Downgrade) Node.js Using npm](https://www.surrealcms.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using-npm.html)*

Answer (score 9):

The problem occurred for me in Visual Studio's **Task Runner Explorer** only and not when running from the command line or PowerShell.

I realised that VS was ignoring the Node version I had set with **NVM**.

This post gave the answer: [Configure which NPM is used by Visual Studio's Task Runner Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010389/configure-which-npm-is-used-by-visual-studios-task-runner-explorer) by setting the **PATH** variable as a higher priority than external tools in VS, it used the Node version set by NVM and not the version installed with VS.
[image]

Comment: This was my issue and the simplicity of verification/remedy of this problem makes me wish I could upvote this twice and I *really* wish I would've seen this first.

Answer (score 8):

In case the problem is not from `gulp` then check the [unzip](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip) npm module. It's been around six years since the last time it was updated. It doesn't work with Node.js > v11.

Try this:

```
npm install -g n

sudo n 11.15.0
```

Comment: Same with `unzip2`. However, `unzip2` has a replacement that works - `node-unzip-2`

Comment: Had the same issue on my project. Moved to `unzipper` fork instead https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip/issues/122#issuecomment-492099935

Answer (score 6):

Downgrading to Node.js stable fixed this issue for me, as it occurred after I upgraded to Node.js 12:

```bash
sudo n 10.16.0
```

Comment: If you try this and get the error: 'sudo: n: command not found', be sure to install `n` first with: 'npm install -g n'

Comment: Tryed this on Windows 10 (64 bit) and got :- C:\react-script-editor>npm install -g n
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@6.1.0: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

Comment: Downgrading is not an option. We need a fix and not a bandaid solution.

Answer (score 6):

This error is because of the **new version of Node.js** (12) and **an old version of Gulp** (less than 4).

Downgrading Node.js and other dependencies isn't recommended. I solved this by updating `package.json` file, fetching the latest version of all dependencies. For this, I use `npm-check-updates`. It is a module that updates the `package.json` with the latest version of all dependencies.

**Reference**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

In most cases, we will have to update the `gulpfile.js` as well like the following:

**Reference**: *[Gulp 4: The new task execution system - gulp.parallel and gulp.series, Migration](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/#migration)*

Before:

```
gulp.task(
    'sass', function () {
        return gulp.src([sourcePath + '/sass/**/*.scss', "!" + sourcePath + "/sass/**/_*.scss"])

            ....
    }
);

Other configuration...

gulp.task(
    'watch', function () {
        gulp.watch(sourcePath + '/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    }
);
```

After:

```
gulp.task('sass', gulp.series(function(done) {
    return gulp.src([sourcePath + '/sass/**/*.scss', "!" + sourcePath + "/sass/**/_*.scss"])

            ...

    done();
}));

Other config...

gulp.task(
    'watch', function () {
        gulp.watch(sourcePath + '/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    }
);
```

Comment: Great solution if you don't have complex gulp files. In my case, I only had to adapt two lines per gulpfile.js. Thanks for the short migration guide!

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue. What I tried and what worked for me:

1. Check the version of *Node.js* and *Gulp.js* (a combination of Node.js v12 and Gulp.js less than v4 doesn't work)
2. I downgraded the NPM version by:

   ```bash
   sudo NPM install -g n
   sudo n 10.16.0
   ```

It worked fine. Then just follow the instructions of your console.

Answer (score 4):

- Remove package-lock.json or yarn.lock file.
- Then remove node_modules.
- After that modify the package.json file-

  "dependencies": {
  "gulp": "^4.0.0"
  }
- Then run- npm install

It will be enough to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error on Windows 10. It turned out to be a corrupted roaming profile.

```
npm ERR! node v12.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12

npm ERR! primordials is not defined
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Deleting the `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder fixed my issue.

Comment: This messed up my whole npm dependencies, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue on Windows 10 by uninstalling Node.js from *Add or Remove Programs* → Node.js.

Then I installed version 11.15.0 from https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.15.0/

Choose *node-v11.15.0-x64.msi* if you're running Windows 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to 4.0.1 and make sure to migrate https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/#migration

Comment: Did that, no dice.

Comment: It's not that easy unfortunately. Gulp 4.x.x is massively incompatible with Gulp 3.x.x. The Gulpfile will essentially need to be rewritten from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

If keeping Node.js v12 while using the latest gulp ^4.0, follow these steps:

Update the command-line interface (just for precaution) using:

```
npm i gulp-cli -g
```

Add/Update the `gulp` under dependencies section of your *package.json* file

```
"dependencies": {
  "gulp": "^4.0.0"
}
```

Delete your `package-lock.json` file.

Delete your `node_modules` folder.

Finally, run `npm i` to upgrade and recreate a brand new *node_modules* folder and *package-lock.json* file with correct parameters for Gulp ^4.0:

```
npm i
```

**Note** Gulp.js 4.0 introduces the `series()` and `parallel()` methods to combine tasks instead of the array methods used in Gulp 3, and so you may or may not encounter an error in your old `gulpfile.js` script.

To learn more about applying these new features, [this site](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-to-gulp-4/) have really done justice to it: *[How to Migrate to Gulp.js 4.0](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-to-gulp-4/)*

Comment: What's the `gulp-cli` for? I followed your steps and got everything working initially; but then I uninstalled `gulp-cli` (since I didn't see where it was being used), and everything still worked. Thanks for the answer, though, because I'm up and running again with node `v12.9.1` and Gulp `4.0.2`!

Comment: I am glad it helped. `gulp-cli` is command line utility. Its ensures proper installation of gulp

As you can see in gulp installation steps here: https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to install `semantic-ui` and the following error occurs then try downloading the latest version of Node.js `js(13.5.0)` with the latest features, from Node.js.org.

Moreover, rather than trying the NPM install semantic, you should just add the link (which you can find from the [cdnjs link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui)) to the header of your `index.html` file.

Comment: Code example would be a great addition here.

Comment: What does *"the following error"* refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Gulp is making issue with Node.js version 11 and above. Uninstall your current Node.js version and reinstall the `v10.15.1` version. Here is the link for that version. This helps me and it will solve your problem too.

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.15.1/

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a lot of suggestions to fix this problem for an existing project on my Windows 10 machine and ended up following these steps to fix it;

- Uninstall Node.js from "Add or remove programs". Fire up a new Command prompt and type `gulp -v` and then `node -v` to check that it has been uninstalled completely.
- Download and install Node.js [v10.16.0](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.16.0/) - not the latest as latest node & gulp combination is causing the problem as far as I see. During installation I didn't change the installation path which I normally do(C:\Program Files\nodejs).
- Open up a new Command prompt, go to your project's directory where you have got your gulpfile.js and start gulp as shown in the image.

Please note sometimes when I switch between git branches I might need to close my Visual Studio and run it as Admin again in order to see this solution working again.

As far as I see this problem started to happen after I installed the latest recommended version(12.18.4) of Node.js for a new project and I only realised this when some FE changes weren't reflected on the existing web project.

Update: Today I had the same problem while setting up one of my existing projects on my new PC and I did the same steps + went to the directory where I have the gulpfile and then run `npm install`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Install gulp and add your Node.js version to the *package.json* file like so:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "node":  "^10.16.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you've upgraded your nodejs's version to be +12 and still using gulp 3.9.1

You can use one of the below solutions

- Upgrade you glup version to be +4
- Or simply you use **[NVM](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/run-multiple-nodejs-version-on-the-same-machine/)** Node version Manager
  To run multiple nodejs versions on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same error, but it was caused by a different issue.

```
OS: windows 10
nodejs version: 15.12.0
npm version: 7.6.3
```

The cause of the problem was **graceful-fs** package.
Whenever I tried to run npm, even running npm-v was firing "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined".

I tried running npm install graceful-fs@latest, but it still didn't work, even though the package was latest version.

**So what helped me?**

run `npm ls graceful-fs`

This way you'll find all packages on which `graceful-fs` is dependency and which version it has. In my case it was mostly version 3.0, even though I've installed version 4.2.6

**So how to fix it?**

Open npm-shrinkwrap.json (not sure about packages-lock.json) and change search for `graceful-fs` - you'll see that it has older versions on a few places. Replace it with `^4.2.6` (or newer).

Then `npm audit fix --force` which will forcefully install the newer version everywhere.

Hope this works for you, it took me a few hours to find out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is old but may still relevant as there are many projects still using gulp v3.

As upgrading gulp would require more changes - for many years the main solution we used was downgrading node version, however this becomes more and more of a problem.

The simplest fix for us these days - without compromising on node version - was to add those two lines to as the last block of /package.json file :

```
"overrides": {
  "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11",
  "ttf2woff2": "^4.0.4"
}
```

After adding it - run "npm install" to tell gulp to address the added lines and then gulp v3 would work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/):

```bash
yarn global add n
n 11.15.0
yarn install # Have to install again
```

Comment: Please do not use a shortliving NodeJS branch (all odd version numbers like 9 and 11), use NodeJS 10.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here

1. Either upgrade to gulp 4 or else
2. downgrade to an earlier Node.js version.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the compatibility issue between `node` and `gulp` in your system. Downgrading the `node` or upgrading the `gulp` will fix this issue.

```
sudo npm i -g n
sudo n 11.15.0
```

Try removing the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and installing again using `npm i` command if still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue installing the npm package [webshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webshot).

NOTE: it was a known issue for that package as it depends on graceful-fs behind the scenes.

**Fix: 1.** **upgrade graceful-fs  to 4.x or higher**

**Fix: 2.** **use webshot-node instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/webshot-node**

Answer (score 0):

Since my project was using gulp version 4, I had to do the following to solve this

1. Delete folder *node_modules*
2. open package.json and update version

[image: Issue]

[image: Update]

Here is the detail of version I am using

[image: Version]

Now run npm install and then run gulp default. The error should be gone and you may see:

> Task never defined: default only.

Answer (score 0):

For me after using series() to combine task the problem was solved.

Any of the answer here was not solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you first make sure **NPM install** is not your problem. Then you downgrade Node.js and Gulp.js versions. I used Node.js 10.16.1 and Gulp.js 3.9.1.

To downgrade your Gulp.js installation, you can try:

```bash
npm install gulp@^3.9.1
```

Answer (score -2):

Using Python 2 (executable `python`) during *npm* installation worked for me:

```
npm install --python=~/venv/bin/python
```

Answer (score -2):

We also get this error when we use the s3 NPM package. So the problem is with the graceful-fs package - we need to update it. It is working fine on 4.2.3.

So just look in what NPM package it is showing in the logs trace and update graceful-fs accordingly to 4.2.3.

Answer (score -2):

For anyone having the same error for the same reason in ADOS CI Build:

This question was the first I found when looking for help.
I have an ADOS CI build pipeline where the first Node.js tool installer task is used to install Node.js. Then npm task is used to install Gulp.js (npm install -g gulp). Then the following Gulp.js task runs default-task from gulpfile.js. There's some gulp-sass stuff in it.

When I changed the Node.js tool to install 12.x latest node instead of an older one and the latest Gulp.js version was 4.0.2. The result was the same error as described in the question.

What worked for me in this case was to downgrade Node.js to latest 11.x version as was already suggested by Alphonse R. Dsouza and Aymen Yaseen. In this case though there's no need to use any commands they suggested, but rather just set the Node.js tool installer version spec to latest Node.js version from 11.x.

[image]

The exact version of Node.js that got installed and is working was 11.15.0. I didn't have to downgrade Gulp.js.

Answer (score -2):

I was also getting an error on Node.js 12/13 with Gulp.js 3. Moving to Node.js 11 worked.

Answer (score -2):

I solved by downgrading Node.js version from `12.14.0` to `10.18.0` and reinstalling `node_modules`.

Answer (score -2):

I was using Node.js v12.13.1, so I've downgraded to v10.19.0. It worked fine after that.

Answer (score -2):

Steps to fix the problem:

I have fixed the problem with the following steps:

1. Installing NVM
2. Installed lts/dubnium using command `nvm install lts/dubnium`
3. Use lts/dubnium using command `nvm install lts/dubnium`

Now you can you gulp deploy.

Comment: This is an inaccurate dupe of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56328843/3272856) of @kevink

Answer (score -5):

For anyone that is running into this please confirm you haven't done the silly thing I did and accidentally ran `npm init` in your user directory a million years ago and forgot to clear out those files.

I found this issue when trying to use `@vue-cli` to create a new project and it ended up being a rogue `package.json` / `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder in the root of my user directory.

**Solution**: Delete `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, and `node_modules` from your user directory and voila, problem solved! Now, remove the palm from the forehead!

Comment: Unless you're using npm of course, that would be devastating for your project :)