# NodeJS - Uncaught ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So that's all, I'm developing a program with electron, everything worked good, as if on wheels, until,
I do my little npm start, as usual, I test my application a little, and I see that the javascript does not work anymore
So, I do a little 'Ctrl + Shift + I' and I see in the console, that none of my modules have been imported, because at the very top, we have a great error:
'Uncaught ReferenceError: primordials is not defined' in 'inspect.js'
I searched all over the internet, and the few answers I found, are people who have a problem with gulp and who do not have the right version, except that I do not use gulp so it does not can not come from there

That's all, so if someone has a solution, I'm interested!

- node -v > v10.15.3
- npm -v > 5.3.0 (I've tested with 6.9.0 too)

thank you in advance

Comment: I see you're fairly new to StackOverflow -- welcome! Honestly you don't have a lot of technical information in your post, so it's going to be __really__ hard for anyone to help you here. Maybe post some of the code that seems to be throwing that error?

Comment: I understand that it can be complicated, if there was code to give I would give it without problem I would have done from the beginning, but the problem is that between the moment I had no error and between the moment I got this error, I did not change anything in the code! The error arrived like that at once!

Comment: In only have this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at VM19 inspect.js:70`

Comment: Ow! I've find where is the problem! The problem pops when I use 'unzip' nodejs module, because it use 'natives' plugin, any solution?

Answer (score -1):

I met a similar error today and I just solved the problem. Check this link :

[How to Fix ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node)

My error is the same as described in the link. The problem is that the combination of node 12 and gulp 3 does not work. So I downgrade node to v11.15.0. It really works!

You can try it. Hope it can help you!

Comment: I said i do not use gulp ^^ so the problem can't came from there