# NativeScript Sidekick - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: primordials is not defined

Tags: node.js, windows, gulp, nativescript, sidekick

When starting up NativeScript Sidekick, I am presented an exception from the Windows stating the following (this error message also shows up in the output Errors in Sidekick): `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: primordials is not defined` (for easier reading the full stack trace of the error can be found at the bottom)

I have literally not done anything except install NativeScript Sidekick and open the application.

How do I resolve this issue?

```
(CLI) (node:6632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:35
    at req_ (userFolder\AppData\Roaming\.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (userFolder\AppData\Roaming\.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (userFolder\AppData\Roaming\.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (userFolder\AppData\Roaming\.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at emitWarning (internal/process/promises.js:120:15)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:168:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:90:32)
(node:6632) ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:35
    at req_ (userFolder\AppData\Roaming\.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (userFolder\AppData\Roaming\.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (userFolder\AppData\Roaming\.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (userFolder\AppData\Roaming\.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
```

More information from the console:

```
NativeScript Sidekick version: 1.16.2-v.2019.3.13.12
Dependencies versions: NodeJS: 12.1.0, npm: 6.4.1, NativeScript CLI: 5.3.4.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that **NativeScript Sidekick** must be using **gulp 3**.

I found this answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926692/2523968) talking about a similar issue, but not related to NativeScript Sidekick.

Must sure that your current installed **node** version is not **12**, because **node v12** and **gulp 3** do not work together, as you can see [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2324)

To check your node version run the following in Terminal:

```
$ node -v
```

Since we can't change the **gulp** version of **NativeScript Sidekick** ourselves, the best solution is to downgrade the node version.

At the time of writing this the Latest **LTS** version is `10`. Downgrading to this version resolves the exception error message.

Comment: Restarting Sidekick was also needed.