# Requiring external babel register error during npm start

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, gulp, babeljs

I started angular Application via npm start with gulp/babel enabled.
After starting, the browser page keeps loading and is throwing an error "requiring external babel register".

given below logs from terminal:

```
[19:52:47] Requiring external module @babel/register
[19:52:53] Using gulpfile ~\WebstormProjects\agent-dealer-portal-frontend\portals-integration\front\gulpfile.babel.js
[19:52:53] Starting 'default'...
```

babel-register is listed properly in the terminal.

```
C:\Users\vramanathan\WebstormProjects\agent-dealer-portal-frontend\portals-integration\front>npm list babel-register
@globant/cna_national_portal@0.35.0 C:\Users\vramanathan\WebstormProjects\agent-dealer-portal-frontend\portals-integration\front
`-- babel-cli@6.26.0
  +-- babel-core@6.26.3
  | `-- babel-register@6.26.0  deduped
  `-- babel-register@6.26.0
```

.babelrc file contents:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
    "main": "gulpfile.babel.js",
    "name": "@globant/cna_national_portal",
    "version": "00.35.00",
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/env"
        ],
        "compact": false
    },
    ......
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/register": "^7.5.5",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
        "del": "^3.0.0",
        "eslint": "^5.0.1",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
        "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
        "gulp-cli": "^1.4.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
        "gulp-eslint": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-header": "^1.8.9",
        "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
        "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.4.0",
        "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-rev": "^8.1.1",
        "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.4.4",
        "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
        "gulp-sass-glob": "^1.0.8",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.11.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
        "gulp-uncss": "^1.0.6",
    },
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "gulp",
        "build": "gulp build --production",
        "test": "gulp test",
        "test:watch": "gulp test:watch",
        "eslint": "gulp eslint"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node/55926692#55926692) may be useful: there is some incompatibilities between certain versions of *Node / gulp* when that arise when using different OSs (I'm on Chromebook for my work).

For me, **downgrading** to Node 10 solved my issue (via command): `nvm use 10`