# Configure which NPM is used by Visual Studio's Task Runner Explorer?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, task-runner-explorer

In a usual Windows command line I see:

```
C:\Users\me\myProject\UI> node --version
v8.12.0

C:\Users\me\myProject\UI> npm --version
6.11.3

C:\Users\me\myProject\UI> where node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

C:\Users\me\myProject\UI> where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd
```

Now I am working with Visual Studio Professional 2017: If I open up a (Powershell) terminal via **Tools > NuGet Packet Manager > Package Manager console**, I see the global installation I favor:

```
PM> pwd

Path                                                                 
----                                                                 
C:\myProject

PM> Get-Command npm

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                                                                                           
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                                                                                           
Application     npm.cmd                                            0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd   

PM> node --version
v8.12.0
PM> npm --version
6.11.3
PM> Get-Command node

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                                                                                           
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                                                                                           
Application     node.exe                                           8.12.0.0   C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

However, if I choose `Defaults > version` within the [Task Runner Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TaskRunnerExplorer), I see the following output:

```
C:\me\myProject> cmd.exe /c npm run version --color=always
> myProject.ui@1.3.7 version C:\me\myProject
> node --version
v10.6.0
```

That's not the version I want, and neither any of the installations I saw in the command window in the beginning with `where npm`!

The only way that this is possible is that there is another installation somewhere which is chosen because of the PATH-settings within the Task Runner Explorer. Is that a correct conclusion? **I want also the Task Runner Explorer to use the global installation, but how do I do that?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is described at https://github.com/madskristensen/NpmTaskRunner/issues/66 as my colleague just told me. The solution is straight-forward, but only if you know where to look.

1. Go to **Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools**
2. In the appearing pop-up window, use the arrow-buttons to move the entry `$(PATH)` to the 2nd position (it is probably further down in the list)

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Configuration Popup Window]