# What's the approach to figure out the Node.js dependent module crash?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My Node.js app run well before. I put this Node.js app aside for several months and return back to continue to develop it on a new machine. Error happens!!!
Error information is as follows:

```
fs.js:27
const { Math, Object } = primordials;
                         ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:26
    at req_ (/Users/xiaoningchang/Documents/Code/udfinder/avdetector/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/Users/xiaoningchang/Documents/Code/udfinder/avdetector/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xiaoningchang/Documents/Code/udfinder/avdetector/node_modules/graceful-ncp/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
```

And my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "meminsight",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "JavaScript memory analyses",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Samsung/meminsight.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "acorn": "3.1.0",
    "argparse": "0.1.15",
    "aspect-js": "^1.0.3",
    "callsites": "^2.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "codemirror": "5.1.0",
    "cover": "0.2.9",
    "datatables": "^1.10.18",
    "ejs": "1.0.0",
    "escope": "1.0.1",
    "esotope": "1.4.5",
    "estraverse": "4.0.0",
    "execSync": "1.0.2",
    "expect.js": "^0.3.1",
    "express": "3.4.8",
    "fast-stats": "0.0.2",
    "finalhandler": "0.0.3",
    "graceful-ncp": "2.0.0",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "jquery": "2.1.3",
    "jsonparse": "0.0.6",
    "line-by-line": "0.1.3",
    "line-reader": "^0.4.0",
    "log4js": "^2.3.11",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.0",
    "mocha": "^1.20.1",
    "multi-key-cache": "^1.0.2",
    "parse5": "2.1.5",
    "q": "1.2.0",
    "rewriting-proxy": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "serve-static": "^1.14.1",
    "sloc": "^0.2.1",
    "temp": "0.8.1",
    "websocket": "^1.0.30",
    "wrench": "1.5.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "(cat test/testSuite.txt | sed 's/^/test\\//' | xargs ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter spec --harmony) && cd lifetime-analysis && ./gradlew cleanTest test && cd ..",
    "build": "grunt typescript"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-cli": "0.1.13",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "grunt-simple-mocha": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-typescript": "^0.8.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

It seems that something wrong in the the dependent module `natives`. However, according to the `package.json` file, the app do not rely on `natives` module. In addition, there is not variable named `primordials` in `index.js` file of `natives` module.

Additonal information:
Version of Node.js: 12.10.0;
Version of npm: 6.11.3;
I also encounter an error that `gyp ERR! build error` when I `npm install` the app. I use the command `npm audit fix` to fix it. Is this related to my issue?

Could anyone help me about this issue? I am new to Node.js and have less experience to debug out of myself codes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your new machine, has the same OS than your old machine? It is a server machine, or your local development one? Did you try to `rm -rf node_modules; npm install` yet? The node version is the same?

Comment: Have you tried general solutions like `npm i` and updating Node and npm? It seems like a native module is trying to extract a property from an undeclared variable which obviously isn't your problem.

Comment: @Sergeon The OS are different. I am not sure whether the version of node is same. I just `rm -rf nodule_modules` and `npm install` but the same error appears again.

Comment: @MohammedMortaga. I just `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm i`. But the same issue appears again.

Comment: @Sergeon I just check the version of Node on my previous machine, which is 11.6.0. Is the verison of node related to my issue?

Comment: Sometimes your Node version can make a whole lot of difference especially when it comes to transpilers and other modules. Try playing around with your Node and npm version, I'm sure you'll get somewhere. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node)

Answer (score 1):

The natives npm package is deprecated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/natives.

If you go its page, they warn about that the package may break in future node versions -- they seriously suggest against using the package in the first place, too. I guess either a different OS or node version is the culprit here. The fact that you don't have natives listed in your `package.json` as dependency, means that at least one of your dependencies is using natives -or a dependency of one of your dependencies and so on...-.

One way you can check which dependencies are using natives is to run:

`$ npm ls natives`

I installed your dependencies in a project in my local machine -MacOS 10- and run it, and it appears that `graceful-fs` is using `natives`. `graceful-fs` is a dependency of `graceful-ncp`, which is listed in your package.json.

When I did `$npm install` I got several warnings, one of them about upgrading `graceful-fs` to version 4 to avoid future errors when upgrading node version.

The `graceful-ncp` package is currently on version 3.0.0, so I upgraded the version in `package.json` to 3.0.0. Then `$ rm -rf node_modules && npm i`;

After that, `$ npm ls natives` yields empty, which means upgrading `graceful-ncp` version should fix your problem - of course, you may need to add changes to your code to avoid breaking changes of `graceful-ncp`.

Comment: Your suggestion saves me! Thanks very much!