# All npm commands are throwing the same error, including version check(npm -v). Unlike other questions Not a single npm command is working

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Installed Node version 12.13.0 on windows 10. All npm commands throws the following error:

```
   C:\Users\Jahangeer> npm -v
   evalmachine.<anonymous>:27
   const { Math, Object } = primordials;
                     ^

   ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
       at evalmachine.<anonymous>:27:26
       at Object.<anonymous> 
   (C:\Users\Jahangeer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
       at Object.<anonymous> 
   (C:\Users\Jahangeer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful- 
   fs.js:3:27)
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
```

Tried uninstalling and installing few other older Node versions. The Problem remains.

Comment: `npm cache clean --f` try to clean the cache

Comment: Are you using gulp3?

Comment: @JaydipJadhav Tried the command, same error message.

Comment: @AyushGupta I'am new to node & npm. Trying to install angular cli for angular projects.

Comment: I can't run any npm commands including npm install, to change gulp version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node)

Comment: @MapLion its not a duplicate, since no npm commands are working for me...

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands to install node 11 and gulp 3 and check:

npm install -g n

sudo n 11.15.0

npm install gulp@^3.9.1
npm install 
npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: Is npm added to your path in environment variables??. Please check and add if not added.

Comment: " C:\Users\Jahangeer\AppData\Roaming\npm "  was already in the 'path' environment variable. After googling i added the following path also  "  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin ". Neither of them could'nt solve the problem. @Himanshu

Comment: Add C:\Program Files\nodejs\ in Path under System Variables under Environment variables and check.

Comment: Tried adding ' c:\Program Files\nodejs\ ' as the only npm reference in the path variable, still same error shows.

Comment: I think c in the path should be Capital "C:\Program Files\nodejs\". Add them under system variables in Path variable and check.

Comment: Typo here in the comment bro, path variable has correct path.

Comment: Check if this is the root cause of your error. https://dev.to/only8britt/referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-140a

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RamachandraAPai. The solution provided in the website is for a project(older). My problem is not with a project, but with the NPM itself, since none of the NPM related commands are working in my system.