# gulp Package task -ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: node.js, gulp, saas, gulp-sass, sitecore-habitat

Team,

My Ci Pipeline azure getting failed find error below.
I have tried solution from [How to fix ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node) but no luck

Error below :

```
##[section]Starting: gulp Package-Generate
==============================================================================
Task         : Gulp
Description  : Node.js streaming task based build system
Version      : 0.141.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613721)
==============================================================================
[command]C:\npm\prefix\gulp.cmd Package-Generate --gulpfile d:\a\1\s\gulpfile.js --configuration release
fs.js:27
const { Math, Object } = primordials;
                         ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:26
    at req_ (d:\a\1\s\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (d:\a\1\s\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\a\1\s\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
##[error]Gulp failed with error: C:\npm\prefix\gulp.cmd failed with return code: 1
##[section]Finishing: gulp Package-Generate
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node)

Comment: @Tobias : it was fixed by architect ,so not sure about the solution.

Answer (score 14):

I was getting this error while I was using `Gulp 3.9.1` and `NodeJS 12.14.0`.

I have solved uninstalling `NodeJS 12.14.0` and installing `NodeJS 10.13.0` version.

Then everything worked properly.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by using the Node.js tool installer and targeted node version 10x.  Make this your first task.  This made it so I didn't have to upgrade gulp to 4.  I'm building on ubuntu-16.04

[image: build pipeline]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Microsoft hosted agents, the version of nodejs is [automatically updated](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/83eb28f760cb8ecd808eb9f6f740a854398ebb99/images/linux/scripts/installers/nodejs.sh#L11) to the latest LTS.

So now you have to update your build to use Gulp 4. I found [this blog](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-to-gulp-4/) helpful for the migration.