# unable to upgrade yarn package or dependencies (semantic-ui/rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui, yarnpkg

I would like to upgrade to the latest version of Semantic UI to see if some issues regarding content security policy have been fixed. I type `yarn upgrade semantic-ui` to upgrade, and get the following output:

```
yarn upgrade v1.22.4
warning package.json: No license field
warning No license field
warning No license field
warning No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > hawk@3.1.3: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > hawk > hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > hawk > boom@2.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > hawk > boom > hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > hawk > sntp@1.0.9: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > hawk > sntp > hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > hawk > cryptiles@2.0.5: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > hawk > cryptiles > boom@2.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > chokidar > readdirp > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > chokidar > readdirp > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning semantic-ui > gulp-watch > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning semantic-ui > gulp > gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
warning semantic-ui > gulp-dedupe > gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
warning semantic-ui > gulp > vinyl-fs > glob-stream > minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
warning semantic-ui > gulp > vinyl-fs > glob-stream > glob > minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
warning semantic-ui > gulp > vinyl-fs > graceful-fs > natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
warning semantic-ui > gulp-concat-css > rework > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning semantic-ui > gulp > vinyl-fs > glob-watcher > gaze > globule > minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
warning semantic-ui > gulp > vinyl-fs > glob-watcher > gaze > globule > glob > minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
warning semantic-ui > gulp > vinyl-fs > glob-watcher > gaze > globule > glob > graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697".
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "better-console@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "del@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "extend@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-autoprefixer@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-chmod@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-clean-css@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-clone@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-concat@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-concat-css@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-copy@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-dedupe@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-flatten@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-header@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-help@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-if@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-less@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-notify@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-plumber@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-print@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-rename@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-replace@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-rtlcss@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-uglify@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "gulp-watch@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "map-stream@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "replace-ext@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "require-dot-file@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "run-sequence@*".
warning " > semantic-ui@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "yamljs@*".
[4/4]   Rebuilding all packages...
[-/4] ⠄ waiting...
[4/4] ⠄ semantic-ui
[3/4] ⠄ node-sass
error /Users/meeee/code/project/node_modules/semantic-ui: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: gulp install
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/meeee/code/project/node_modules/semantic-ui
Output:
fs.js:27
const { Math, Object } = primordials;
                         ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:26
    at req_ (/Users/meeee/code/project/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/Users/meeee/code/project/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/meeee/code/project/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
```

I don't entirely understand what's happening with the very last portion, but I can see up top that I have unmet peer dependencies. Trying to install them myself is circuitous - the entire problem repeats itself.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most desirable solution, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59458271/2009652) helped. *Downgrading* to node `10.13.0` fixed the problem and allowed me to upgrade my dependencies.