# ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node.js

Tags: node.js, gulp

I was install node modules by npm install, then I've tried gulp sass-watch in terminal. and get ReferenceError: primordials is not defined error like below Please Help Me with This:-

```
 [12:13:28] Requiring external module babel-register
 fs.js:27
 const { Math, Object, Reflect } = primordials;
                                  ^
 ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
```

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: It's a very same duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node. I guess it could help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just downgrade you node package into a stable version like 10.13.0 and then re-install the node modules.it will work