# Grunt Serve stopped working with cdnify load error

Tags: angular, gruntjs, bower

I am facing error with fresh installed Angular when I run `grunt serve` command I get

I am using Node 12.6.1 with Source Tree and verified that bower is installed

```
Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 1 path cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

    Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

    Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
    Copied 3 files

    Done.


    Execution Time (2020-02-21 18:22:53 UTC+5:30)
    loading tasks  13ms  ███████████ 22%
    copy:styles    45ms  █████████████████████████████████████ 78%
    Total 58ms

Running "autoprefixer:server" (autoprefixer) task
>> 3 autoprefixed stylesheets created.

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node, this is for gulp, but looks similar

Comment: When you run `npm update` or `npm install` do you see anything related to a deprecated package?

Answer (score 12):

The cdnify plugin is outdated and not maintained anymore. You can use one of the replacements. I use [grunt-google-cdn2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-google-cdn2)

**Step 1:** add the package

`npm install --save grunt-google-cdn2`

**Step 2:** change the *grunt-cdnify* plugin loader to use the new package in your *Gruntfile.js*

Your Gruntfile.js might differ, but you need to change the plugin you use from *grunt-cdnify* to *grunt-google-cdn2*.

```
// Automatically load required Grunt tasks
require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn2',
    chokidar: 'grunt-chokidar',
    serveStatic: 'serve-static',        
});
```

**Step 3:** Remove the old grunt-cdnify plugin from your *package.json*