# ReferenceError: primordials is not defined error when installing Semantic UI

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I know that this question had been asked a lots of times (for instance - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)), but either solutions didn't work or didn't fit my scenario.
The solution, offered in the link above, was:

> Solution: Either upgrade to gulp 4 or downgrade to an earlier node.

So, here's what I have:

• Node: 12.18.1 (`node -v`)

• Gulp: CLI 2.3.0, Local version 4.0.2 (`gulp -v`)

I have created brand new react app:

```
npx create-react-app --template typescript react-app
```

Then I go to app folder (react-app) and execute the following command as on [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) site:

```
npm install semantic-ui --save
```

However, I get the same error as in the question above. Here's the full output of this command:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going back to Node v10.
The thing is that Node v12 has a feature that is not compatible with Semantic-UI (Gulp 4.0.2), and that's why you get the error.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to roll back your version of Node, try using the actively maintained community fork of Semantic UI: [Fomantic UI](https://fomantic-ui.com/).

Run the command as you would with semantic-ui: `npm i fomantic-ui`

Fomantic is backwards-compatible with Semantic UI while resolving compatibility issues between Node 12 and Gulp 3 (which [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node) references as being the root of the "primordials is not defined" issue).

Comment: This worked for me...I was having trouble on Windows builds where Linux builds worked as-is. Gulp won't update to 4 on Windows - gets to 3.9.

Comment: This should be the accepter answer. Thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try upgrading your node.js to the latest version at https://nodejs.org/en/download/

and also run the following command `npm install -g npm@7.0.9` or the latest version to update your npm.
After upgrading and updating Node and npm I installed semantic-ui without getting the *primordial not defined error*.