# NPM ERROR: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, gulp

I want to launch this frontend project on my local machine, but unfortunately recieving this error messages:

```
NPM START
```

```
> gitbitex@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Dev\webexchange
> gulp

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\Dev\webexchange\node_modules\und
ertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\Dev\webexchange\node_modules\undertaker\lib\t
ask.js:13:8)
    at C:\Users\Dev\webexchange\gulpfile.js:59:25
    at createTask (C:\Users\Dev\webexchange\gulpfile.js:62:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\webexchange\gulpfile.js:178:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gitbitex@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gitbitex@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-26T18_16_26_44
3Z-debug.log
```

And this, when I run `NPM INSTALL`

```
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but n
ed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but
led. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN gitbitex@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN gitbitex@1.0.0 No license field.

audited 1390 packages in 36.603s
found 16 vulnerabilities (12 low, 2 high, 2 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Here is the project I want to compile:
https://github.com/gitbitex/gitbitex-web

#### What I have tried

I changed the version of GULP from package.json into: `^3.9.1` as many people online suggested it !

But unfortunately this comes with another problem:

```
> gitbitex@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Dev\webexchange
> gulp

fs.js:27
const { Math, Object } = primordials;
                         ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
?[90m    at fs.js:27:26?[39m
    at req_ (C:\Users\Dev\webexchange\node_modules\?[4mnatives?[24m\inde
x.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\Dev\webexchange\node_modules\?[
4mnatives?[24m\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dev\webexchange\node_modules\?[4mgra
ceful-fs?[24m\fs.js:1:37)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10
)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)?[39m
?[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)?[39m
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gitbitex@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gitbitex@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-28T23_02_25_470Z-debug.log
```

#### GULP FILE

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    minimist = require('minimist'),
    proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware'),
    plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    history = require('connect-history-api-fallback'),
    del = require('del');

options = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
isProduction = options.env == 'prod';
buildPath = './build/web';
routeBase = '/';
apiProxy = 'https://gitbitex.com:8080/';

function createTask(task, taskName) {
    if (task.type == 'concat') {
        (function (task, taskName) {
            var cleanTaskName = taskName + '.clean';
            var runTaskName = taskName + '.run';
            gulp.task(cleanTaskName, function () {
                return gulp.src(task.build + task.file).pipe(plugins.clean({ force: true }));
            })

            var htmlMinOptions = {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                minifyCSS: true   
            }

            gulp.task(runTaskName, function () {
                return gulp.src(task.src)
                    .pipe(plugins.concat(task.file))
                    .pipe(plugins.if(task.encrypt_js, plugins.uglify()))
                    .pipe(plugins.if(task.encrypt_css, plugins.minifyCss()))
                    .pipe(plugins.if(task.encrypt_html, plugins.htmlmin(htmlMinOptions)))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(task.build))
            })
            return gulp.task(taskName, [cleanTaskName, runTaskName], function () {
                browserSync.reload();
            })
        })(task, taskName)
    }
    else if (task.type == 'copy') {
        (function (task, taskName) {
            var cleanTaskName = taskName + '.clean';
            gulp.task(cleanTaskName, function () {
                return gulp.src(task.build).pipe(plugins.clean({ force: true }));
            })
            return gulp.task(taskName, [cleanTaskName], function () {
                return gulp.src(task.src).pipe(gulp.dest(task.build))
            })
        })(task, taskName)
    }
    else if (task.type == 'less') {
        (function (task, taskName) {
            var cleanTaskName = taskName + '.clean';
            var runTaskName = taskName + '.run';
            gulp.task(cleanTaskName, function () {
                return gulp.src(task.build + task.file).pipe(plugins.clean({ force: true }));
            })
            gulp.task(runTaskName, function () {
                return gulp.src(task.src)
                    .pipe(plugins.less())
                    .pipe(plugins.concat(task.file))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(task.build))
            })
            gulp.task(taskName, [cleanTaskName, runTaskName], function () {
                browserSync.reload();
            })
        })(task, taskName)

    }
    else if (task.type == 'webpack') {
        (function (task, taskName) {
            return gulp.task(taskName, function (callback) {
                webpack(require("./gulp/webpack.config.js")(task, isProduction), function () {
                    browserSync.reload();
                    callback();
                });
            })
        })(task, taskName)
    }
    else if (task.type == 'clean') {
        (function (task, taskName) {
            return gulp.task(taskName, function () {
                return gulp.src(task.src).pipe(plugins.clean({ force: true }));
            });
        })(task, taskName)
    }
    else if (task.type == 'md5') {
        (function (task, taskName) {
            var taskRev = taskName + ".rev",
                taskReplace = taskName + ".replace",
                taskClean = taskName + ".clean",
                manifestName = taskName + ".rev.json";
            gulp.task(taskRev, function () {
                var pipe = gulp.src(task.src).pipe(plugins.rev()).pipe(gulp.dest(task.build))
                    .pipe(plugins.rev.manifest()).pipe(plugins.rename(manifestName)).pipe(gulp.dest(task.build));

                return pipe;
            });
            gulp.task(taskReplace, function () {
                var files = require(task.build + manifestName);
                var pipe = gulp.src(task.page);
                for (var file in files) {
                    console.log(task.page, file, files[file], task.pageBuild);
                    pipe.pipe(plugins.replace(file, files[file]));
                }
                pipe.pipe(gulp.dest(task.pageBuild));
                return pipe;
            });
            gulp.task(taskClean, function () {
                return gulp.src([
                    task.build + "/*.rev.json"
                ]).pipe(plugins.clean({ force: true }));
            });
        })(task, taskName)
    }
}

var tasks = [];

gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        startPath: routeBase,
        server: {
            baseDir: buildPath,
            middleware: [proxy('/api', {
                target: apiProxy,
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug',
            }), history({
                rewrites: [
                    {
                        from: new RegExp( "/^" + routeBase + "assets/(.*)$", "gi"),
                        to: function(context) {
                            return routeBase + 'assets/' + context.match[1]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        from: new RegExp( "/^" + routeBase + "(.*)$", "gi"),
                        to: routeBase + 'index.html'
                    }
                    
                ]
            })]
        }
    });
});
tasks.push('browser-sync');

var config = require('./gulp/gulp.config')(isProduction, buildPath + routeBase);

for (var key in config["base"]) {
    var task = config["base"][key];
    var taskName = "base." + key;
    createTask(task, taskName);
    gulp.watch(task.watch || task.src, [taskName])
    tasks.push(taskName);
}

for (var key in config["prod"]) {
    var task = config["prod"][key],
        taskName = key;
    createTask(task, taskName);
}

resourcePath = buildPath + routeBase

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src([ resourcePath ]).pipe(plugins.clean({ force: true }));
});
gulp.task('clean-assets', function () {
    return gulp.src([ resourcePath + 'assets/']).pipe(plugins.clean({ force: true }));
});


gulp.task("default", ['clean'], function() {
    if(isProduction) {
        return runSequence(tasks, 
        "vendor.script.md5.rev", "vendor.script.md5.replace", "vendor.script.md5.clean",
        "app.script.md5.rev", "app.script.md5.replace", "app.script.md5.clean",
        "app.style.md5.rev", "app.style.md5.replace", "app.style.md5.clean", 
        "app.md5.clean")
    }
    else return runSequence(tasks);
});
```

#### My configuration

Windows: 7 64bit

Node Version: v12.12.0

NPM Version: 6.11.3

Comment: This error `Task function must be specified` we would need to see your gulpfile.js to help.

Comment: @Mark Here it is sir: https://github.com/gitbitex/gitbitex-web/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Already shared the github in the post :)

Thanks again for your help !

Comment: @Mark I just posted the whole file on this post aswell :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by follwing this steps:

Adding this lines to your package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "graceful-fs": "4.2.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58394828/13649649