# Visual Studio Task Runner Explorer - ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: visual-studio, npm, gulp, visual-studio-2019

So I've upgraded to Visual Studio 16.6.3.  When I go to the Task Runner Explorer it doesn't load my gulp file, in the Task Runner Output Window I can see...

```
Failed to run "E:\Projects\...\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
fs.js:35
} = primordials;
    ^
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:35:5
    at req_ (E:\Projects\...\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (E:\Projects\...\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\...\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
```

I then google this find this is due to an [incompatibility between node 12 and gulp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node) with advice to upgrade to version 4.  So I update my package.json file and change from "gulp": "3.9.1" to "gulp": "4.0.2". When I go to the task explorer, I see the following in the Task Runner Output Window ...

```
Failed to run "E:\Projects\...\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (E:\Projects\...\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (E:\Projects\...\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\...\gulpfile.js:86:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at requireOrImport (E:\Projects\...\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js:19:11) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
```

I google this and the advice is to downgrade gulp to version 3... Just once I would like to open the Task Runner Explorer and not spend 4 hours trying to solve dependency issues.

Also running "npm install" from the Visual Studio Package Manager Console inside Visual Studio (elevated or not) just seems to result in a bunch of permission errors. I could only successfully run npm install from an elevated powershell window.

Anyone have a solution for these issues?

Package.json is as follows...

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "4.1.1",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-config": "0.3.0",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-csso": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "5.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "2.4.0",
    "gulp-less": "4.0.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "1.2.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "3.0.2",
    "gulp.spritesmith": "^6.10.0",
    "merge-stream": "2.0.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "1.0.1"
  }
}
```

EDIT: Attempted to upgrade from Node from 12.6.2 to 12.18.2 without success.

EDIT: Attempted to upgrade from Node from 12.6.2 to 14.5.0 without success.

Comment: "the advice is to downgrade gulp to version 3" - that is bad advice.  `Task function must be specified` is a common error caused by migrating from gulp v3 to gulp v4 and is usually easily fixed.  But you have to show your gulp v4 gulpfile.js for further help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found a solution that does **not** require downgrading **node** or **gulp**, [credit](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1188/how-to-solve-gulp-exception-reference-error-primordials-is-not-defined-error).

Create a file named `npm-shrinkwrap.json` at the same level as your `package.json` and fill the file with this content:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "graceful-fs": {
            "version": "4.2.2"
       }
    }
}
```

Now delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` in  the same folder and you should now be good. (`Reload` in the `Task Runner Explorer` of `Visual Studio`.)

Comment: If someone else can verify this is an answer I'll mark it as such

Comment: Got a chance to test your answer setting up a new machine and can verify that the steps you've specified work.

Comment: works for me thanks been looking for this for a while.

Answer (score 5):

I got this issue with Visual Studio 2022, when the automated Task Runner ran the gulp tasks that I set to run whenever the solution builds. Visual Studio ships with its own version of Node.js, which is used by default for the Task Runner Explorer, and I needed to configure Visual Studio to use the node version that I have installed instead.

The answer [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/gulpfile-fails-to-load-after-upgrading-to-vs2019-1/961170#T-N965015) from Joe Davis (Web tools, Microsoft) explains how to do this:

> Visual Studio ships with its own version of Node.js, which is used by
> default for the Task Runner Explorer. If you have a different version
> of Node.js installed on your machine, you can use that one by changing
> the settings in Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Web Package
> Management. Move “$(PATH)” to the top of the list in the “Locations of
> external tools:” listbox.

[image]

Comment: This answer is much more convenient since it doesn't require a modification / reload to your node modules and doesn't potentially interfere when you want to run your gulp tasks from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to downgrade to NodeJs v11.15.0 and use gulp 3.9.1.

If anyone out there has a better option I'd be keen to hear it.

Comment: did you got a fix finally?

Comment: @CommonMan the accepted answer above is the solution