# I get the error: fs.js:36 } = primordials; ^ ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: node.js

I get the following error, my node version is: 12.18
when I run npm start to start my project

```
 fs.js:36
  } = primordials;
^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js:36:5
```

someone answered that its problem with gulp and node 12 ([How to fix ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node))

but I don't use gulp in my project and I don't have gulp installed.

below is my package.json

```json
{
    "name":"myapp",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "description":"",
    "scripts":{
        "start":"node server.js",
        "test":"echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author":"MJX",
    "license":"ISC",
    "dependencies":{
        "body-parser":"^1.19.0",
        "express":"^4.17.1",
        "express-handlebars":"^2.0.1",
        "mssql":"^6.2.1",
        "mysql":"^2.18.1",
        "nodemon":"^1.19.4",
        "npm":"^5.10.0"
    },
    "devDependencies":{
        "handlebars-helper-css":"^0.1.0"
    }
}
```

and my server.js:

```js
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 4300;

var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");

app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({ defaultLayout: "main" }));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

var routes = require("./controllers/burgersController.js");

app.use(routes);

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("App now listening at localhost:" + PORT);
});
```

Comment: when I run npm start

Comment: I updated my question added server.js details also

Comment: Does `found 149 vulnerabilities (81 low, 15 moderate, 52 high, 1 critical)` not concern you? Just installed node 12.18.0 and ran `npm install` with your exact `package.json`. Update your dependencies...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace in your error message that you didn't provide:

```
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:35:5
    at req_ (C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\test\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\test\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\test\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
```

you'll find that the error originates from the `natives` module. Running `npm ls natives`, you can determine that it's a sub-dependency of `express-handlebars`:

```
myapp@1.0.0 C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\test
`-- express-handlebars@2.0.1
  `-- graceful-fs@3.0.12
    `-- natives@1.1.6
```

Your `express-handlebars` dependency is extremely outdated. Updating it from `^2.0.1` to `^5.1.0` fixes your problem, but you really shouldn't ignore the rest of your [audit messages](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit):

```
found 146 vulnerabilities (80 low, 15 moderate, 51 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: My problem was different, but after running npm ls graceful-fs I found all other packages that depend on this one. I saw that most of them need graceful-fs version 3, but this version is having problems with newer nodejs on win 10.
So Manually going through package-lock.json & npm-shrinkwrap.json and changing the required graceful-fs version and then running npm audit fix --force did the job for me.
I've been reading about this problem for hours and only this worked for me.

Comment: I have the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72760385/how-to-solve-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-at-fs-js475-previous. can you help me?

Answer (score 12):

Create a file named `npm-shrinkwrap.json` in the project root folder.

Add the following code to the file:

```
{
   "dependencies": {
      "graceful-fs": {
         "version": "4.2.2"
      }
   }
}
```