# "primordials; ^ ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" using gulp 4.0.2 and node version 11.15.0

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am getting exactly the same symptoms as:
[Answered problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node)

However, I have followed the instructions and downgraded node.

`node --version`

Gives: `11.15.0.`

`gulp -v`

Was showing: `CLI version: 2.3.0 Local version: 3.9.1`

Having read the linked article [Gulp 3 is broken on Node 12 #2324](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2324) and seen that gulp 3 is no longer supported I uninstalled the local Gulp using:

`npm uninstall gulp`

and reinstalled it in the project folder:
`npm install gulp --save-dev`

It now says:
`CLI version: 2.3.0 Local version: 4.0.2`

Lastly if it is relevant: `npm -v`

gives: `6.14.8`

I am still seeing the issue same primordial issue.

The package.json is exactly the same as the whole team's.

I ran `npm install` and `bower install` in the project folder as per our project setup instructions.