# How do I fix semantic ui installation error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I'm trying to install semantic-ui locally on my device but I keep getting the following deprecation errors and the installation process keep terminating.

```
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

> semantic-ui@2.4.2 install C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Education\uni\questions\node_modules\semantic-ui
> gulp install

fs.js:45
} = primordials;
    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:45:5
    at req_ (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Education\uni\questions\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Education\uni\questions\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Education\uni\questions\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
npm WARN rollback Rolling back source-map@0.6.1 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Education\uni\questions\node_modules\concat-with-sourcemaps\node_modules'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\gulp-copy\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\gulp-watch\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN questions@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})  

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! semantic-ui@2.4.2 install: `gulp install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the semantic-ui@2.4.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-29T01_27_16_929Z-debug.log

C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Education\uni\questions>
```

When I try to install mongoose, I still get the error below:

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-29T01_27_16_929Z-debug.log
```

Please, how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node