# Primordials is not defined

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to execute this code but I don't know why it shows error. I'm new at Nodejs, so i attach the code and ss of error please help how to fix this

```
var webshot = require('webshot');
var flatiron = require('flatiron');

var app = flatiron.app;

app.use(flatiron.plugins.http);

app.router.get('/getImage', function() {
      var self = this;
      var requestUrl = this.req.headers['head'];
      console.log(requestUrl); 
      webshot(requestUrl, function(err, renderStream) {
        renderStream.pipe(self.res);
      });
});

app.start(3000,"IP Address");

console.log('Starting Node Server');
```

error =

```
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
fs.js:45
} = primordials;
    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:45:5
    at req_ (c:\Users\HOME\Desktop\NodeScripts\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (c:\Users\HOME\Desktop\NodeScripts\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\HOME\Desktop\NodeScripts\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
Process exited with code 1
```

Comment: What version of node are you using, and what is the output when you run `npm audit` in your project directory?

Comment: node version = v14.15.5
and here is a ss of npm audit [  https://prnt.sc/10b1dfx  ] please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note encountering this kind of issue is not common when using Node.js. The packages [webshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webshot) and [flatiron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatiron) haven't been maintained for 5 years at the time of writing, which is the primary reason they're incompatible with the current version of Node.js.

Typically [when this error is encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55921442/1541563), you either need to use different packages, or downgrade to an older version of Node.js. According to the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926692/1541563), you should be able to downgrade to [Node.js v11](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/), but I highly suggest exploring more recently maintained packages like [capture-website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capture-website) and [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) in order to stick with the latest LTS version of Node.js.