# Still getting `primordials is not defined` even after upgrading to Gulp 4. Any way to fix?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to run Gulp on a project but am getting the error `ReferenceError: primordials is not defined`.

The package did use Gulp 3 so I updated to Gulp 4. But I still get the error.

For Gulp my versions are:

```
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

For Node:

```
v12.18.3
```

My Gulp file is simple:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('less', async function () {
    gulp.src('css/less/app.less')
    .pipe(less({
        paths: [ path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes') ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', async function () {
    gulp.watch(['css/less/*.less', 'css/less/_*.less'], gulp.series('less'));
});
```

Would anyone know what I could do?

Comment: Here are two of the better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60136898/836330 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60921145/836330

Answer (score 0):

You need downgrade node version to 6. There is a nice tool: NVM - Node Version Manager - it's allow to change node version on the fly.

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm