# Getting error ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, saas, gulp-watch

While I am trying to do `gulp build` or `gulp watch` I am getting below error -

```
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:47:5
    at req_ (/Users/testuser/projects/insights/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/Users/testuser/projects/insights/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/testuser/projects/insights/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
```

These are the below modules and there version I've installed.

```
node -v
v16.2.0

npm -v
7.13.0

gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.1
```

I am on MacOS Catalina. Can someone please help me with this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnode.js%5D+primordials

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node-js)

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the exact same issue recently. Actually `gulp 3.9` doesn't work with the latest version of `node`. Either upgrade `gulp` to `v4` or downgrade `node` version. `node v10` worked for me.