# npm install legacy React with semantic-ui and Gulp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I am trying to install a React legacy project, but I have an error. The project is using semantic-ui 2.2.13, that is the library that seems to have the problem.

When I do npm install --legacy-peer-deps, this message appears:

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path c:\src\project\node_modules\semantic-ui
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c gulp installfs.js:47
npm ERR! } = primordials;
....
npm ERR! ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
npm ERR! at fs.js:47:5
...

In the detailed log this message apperas

verbose pkgid semantic-ui@2.4.2 (instead of version 2.2.13)

I have node v16.6.1, npm 7.20.3 and in package.json react ^16.13.0, webpack ^4.23.1 among others

Could you please bring me some light about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, your are getting the error because semantic-ui uses Gulp 4, which is not compatible with Node 12 and above. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node-js) suggests overriding the sub-dependency causing the error.
You may follow the issue in the official semantic-ui repo [here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6818)

This [article](https://timonweb.com/javascript/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-error/) also details how to resolve this error.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally I combined Maven & Docker to automate the installation of the correct version of Node (I think it was 10 or so) and it did the install in a pipeline