# How to fix: primordial is not defined (Node & Protractor)

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I have a protractor project in node. Primordial error will show once we upgrade the node version (>10). This error will not show if the node version is 10. My question is how to fix this error in version > 10 since our Jenkins server is using version 12 of node? Please look at the error below.[image]

Comment: have you tried upgrading node -> removing node modules and reinstalling again (`npm i`)?

Comment: @kevthedevv check the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node-js