# ReferenceError: primordials is not defined after gulp watch command laravel 5.6 project?

Tags: laravel, docker, gulp, laradock

This project working on ubuntu pc docker container name as 'laradock'. now I'm setting up this to the windows local pc. in that case get this error. this is the laravel 5.6 project. composer successfully installed.

I already installed
PHP version 7.3 xampp and
node v16.14.0.
npm -v is 8.3.1
How to fix this error?

[![enter image description here][1[image: ]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtESn.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node-js)

Comment: this was worked for me. thanks!