# gulp primordials is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I am getting this error when I try to run Gulp from the task runner I think its related to me updating my npm project but I am not sure how to fix it. Do I need to install a different version of npm?

```
>Failed to run "C:\WebProjects\ITF\Tool.Web\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
fs.js:47
} = primordials;
^
```

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js:47:5

```
C:\WebProjects\ITF\Tool.Web>npm ls natives
tools@1.0.0 C:\WebProjects\ITF\Tool.Web
`-- gulp@3.9.1
  `-- vinyl-fs@0.3.14
    `-- graceful-fs@3.0.12
      `-- natives@1.1.6
```

Version

```
C:\WebProjects\ITF\Tool.Web>npm -v
8.5.5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your version of npm, you seem to be using Node.js 17.8.0, which is currently the latest version.
Now, Gulp 3 does not work in any currently maintained version of Node.js ([see issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2324)).

You should [upgrade to Gulp 4](https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/how-do-i-update-to-gulp-4/) to fix the error.

Comment: Odd numbered major versions of Node.js become unsupported after 6 months. It may be better to instead use the even numbered 16.x in production, as it will enter long-term support mode later this year whereas 17.x will hit end of life in June. [https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/](About Node.js releases)

Comment: @MarkHanna I think I wasn't clear enough. I wasn't suggesting to use Node.js 17.8.0, rather imagining that this was the version used by the OP basing on the information that the npm version is 8.5.5. I reworded my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Would it be better to downgrade Node.js so Gulp 3 would work? I wouldn’t want to rewrite the gulp script?

Comment: @Jefferson It depends, I'd say, on why you updated your project in the first place. Just note that Gulp 3, like Node.js < 12, is no longer maintained.