# "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" when run "npm run server"

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am  starting the json-server from the project with command "npm run server" and saw this problem. Currentlt, it is a React project.

[Terminal error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTfUL.png)

I have done some research, some suggest to downgrade node.js version and other to create "npm-shrinkwrap.json" in the project. So, what is the main problem of this and how to fix it permanently?

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "json-server -p3001 --watch db.json"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.4.2"
  }
}
```

npm and node.js version:

[Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15WyO.png)

Comment: Did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node-js ?
What is your node version?

Comment: Please [don't post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to re-install node.js. The verisions cause of the this error.