# Is it possible to do custom preinstall scripts for npm from which one is run depending on the environment?

Tags: gradle, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I have a project which requires a `preinstall` script to work correctly, but the problem I face is having different environments (local and servers) which work differently and require different preinstall variables.

For local environment, it is adequate for me to have simply

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    ...
```

But  for server, I need the preinstall to include a no_proxy setting in order for it to work:

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "no_proxy=my.proxy.com npx npm-force-resolutions",
    ...
```

My local (Windows environment) will not work with this no_proxy in the `preinstall` script, and the server won't work without the no_proxy setting, so I'm looking for a possible solution to have a custom preinstall script which will execute depending on the environment, but so far I have not come up with a working solution for this.
I have tried to make own scripts that would be called in my clients `build.gradle` before `npm install` depending on the environment, but so far it has no worked.
This is what I have tried:

```
"scripts": {
"preinstall-dev": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
"preinstall-ci": "no_proxy=my.proxy.com npx npm-force-resolutions",
 ...
```

Then I tried creating a gradle task in my client that would run different script depending on if environment is dev (local) and different if it is other (server)

```
task forceResolutions(type: NpmTask) {
    if ( devEnv == 'true' ) {
        args = ['run', 'preinstall-dev']
    }
    else {
        args = ['run', 'preinstall-ci']
    }
}

npmInstall.dependsOn forceResolutions
```

the `devEnv` is set to be true in my projects `gradle.properties` when I am working locally, and it is always false otherwise.

So far the only way I have gotten local and servers to work is to manually remove the no_proxy and run `npm install` to get the local working and put it back before I push changes to the server, this is not in anyway optimal.

This problem I am facing is related to a known issue [How to fix "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node-js)

so I also have graceful-js in the resolutions, but still I get the

> primordials is not defined

error when I run `npm install` followed by `npm start` locally.

ps. I am not very accustomed to working on frontend tasks, especially frontend build stuff.

pps. my npm version is 6.14.8, my node.js version is 12.19.0 and my gradle-wrapper version is 7.5.1.
I cannot upgrade my versions yet, as it will require massive refactoring elsewhere and is under planning stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay this was my own brain freeze moment, as I had made changes to the client `build.gradle` file, I had completely forgot that I need to make these gradle changes viable.
So my custom scripts work as intended with the new gradle task after I ran

```
gradlew clean build
```

in the project. After that everything worked as intended.