# Grunt >> ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: gruntjs, referenceerror

When trying to execute grunt --help , getting the following error
Loading "bower_task.js" tasks...ERROR

> > ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

I am using node version ->V12.20.1
grunt version ->grunt-cli v1.4.3
grunt v0.4.1
bower version: 1.8.14

Please provide the solutions on how to fix this error.

Note:
I tried installing npm install grunt-bower-task.
I tried the steps mentioned in the [How to fix "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined" in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921442/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-in-node-js) also.
But no luck.

Comment: Please see if this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926692 helps you with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved and I tried the following steps:
--> installed node.js 10.24.0 rather than the higher version

npm install --save-dev
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install bower --save-dev
( instead of npm install bower)

post the above steps, I am able to run the grunt tasks commands such as Grunt prepare, grunt copy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).