# Integrating Semantic UI with a Gatsby Project - build fails due to missing closing ')'

Tags: node.js, less, semantic-ui

```
    failed Building development bundle - 14.691s
    ERROR in ./src/semantic/semantic.less
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
    ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    
    ;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
                                              ^
    Missing closing ')'

    1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
    webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

Following this article (https://www.artembutusov.com/webpack-semantic-ui/) and also checked out the thread here (https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-LESS/issues/38). Downgrading the version for `less` hasn't worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to integrate semantic-ui without following the above linked article.

Run: `npm install semantic-ui-css --save`
Then import at the top level `index.js` page: `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';`

[How to install and use semantic-ui-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803075/how-to-install-and-use-semantic-ui-react)